# TypeScript: How can I specify K is exactly keyof T?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type my `pick` function a little better, here's what I've got:

```
export function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): Partial<T> {
    const ret = Object.create(null)
    for(const key of keys) {
        ret[key] = obj[key]
    }
    return ret
}
```

Here's what I want:

```
export function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): K is keyof T ? T : Partial<T>
```

i.e. if I pass *all* the keys of `T` then I want TypeScript to know that it'll return a complete `T`. If I pass a subset of keys, that will give back a `Partial<T>` (or better yet, something to the effect of if K is in T, then T[K] else `undefined`).

Can I do this? Looks like I can only do `extends` conditionals, not "exactly is" conditionals.

---

Or maybe I can make the return type something like `{[K in keyof T]: T[K]}` but I don't know how to negate `in keyof` to specify the remainder of the keys will be `undefined`

---

The `Pick<>` helper doesn't work here because my implementation is a little different -- I'm not returning an object from the intersection of keys, it'll always return exactly `K` keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you require `K extends keyof T`, exact equality of these two types would be equivalent to the inverse bound - `keyof T extends K`:

```
export function pick<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, keys: K[]): keyof T extends K ? T : Partial<T> {
    const ret = Object.create(null)
    for(const key of keys) {
        ret[key] = obj[key]
    }
    return ret
}

interface Vals { key1: number, key2: number };

const full: Vals = pick({key1: 1, key2: 2}, ['key1', 'key2']);
const partial: Partial<Vals> = pick({key1: 1, key2: 2}, ['key1']);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzJtAawB4AVAGjgGk5QZgUATAZzkOAE8IE5SA%20ABQQARgCsAXL0rsOzSVQDaAXQCUkmd160Q9JqxoB%20LZIAKAQ1iYzAGzJ84AbwBQcV3DQ5m8KMHgBeOAB5MWAMADo0HzN6ARQka2sVFzcEaAEPFC82TjhNGWYVR2S3Nx8YBRklOACRUQrOJWK4AF8msqQoXDKnVqdMFHooBDM0YDgANRtWB2yOAEZJOIBbYWAoaU4AJkWkFbWWgG4nJwys5ATJSetWAPwiAQcZBbg5jY5tuE3mygUAciffpR-ltfqojqd4GALFgbKZoVZbFdmPZbgRCA8npJXrMPl8fsD5qCVAcgA)